# Reconstructing a binary tree from infix and prefix expressions [python]

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

Ive been spending hours on trying to figure out how to do this, I know the function "buildtree" has to be called recursively to draw but I just cant figure it out, I just need a spoon-fed answer which I can then study, I have tried to do this for so long its just not within my capabilities cause I cant understand the logical flow of things. (Sad thing is I know this will only take a few lines of code)

```
from ListBinaryTree import ListBinaryTree

def buildtree(left_inorder, left_preorder, right_inorder, right_preorder, root, tree):
    #dont know what to do.


def main(): 
    print("Binary Tree reconstructed by glee598:") 
    inorder_seq = input("Please enter the inorder sequence: ")
    preorder_seq = input("Please enter the preorder sequence: ")
    root = preorder_seq[0]
    root_inorder_index = inorder_seq.find(root)

    left_inorder = inorder_seq[:root_inorder_index]
    right_inorder = inorder_seq[root_inorder_index+1:]

    left_preorder = preorder_seq[1:preorder_seq.find(left_inorder[0])+1]
    right_preorder = preorder_seq[preorder_seq.find(left_inorder[0])+1:]

    tree = ListBinaryTree(root)

    buildtree(left_inorder, left_preorder, right_inorder, right_preorder, root, tree)
main()
```

The ListBinaryTree class:

```
class ListBinaryTree:
        """A binary tree class with nodes as lists."""
        DATA = 0    # just some constants for readability
        LEFT = 1
        RIGHT = 2   

    def __init__(self, root_value, left=None, right=None):
        """Create a binary tree with a given root value
        left, right the left, right subtrees        
        """ 
        self.node = [root_value, left, right]

    def create_tree(self, a_list):
        return ListBinaryTree(a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2])

    def insert_value_left(self, value):
        """Inserts value to the left of this node.
        Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
        """
        self.node[self.LEFT] = ListBinaryTree(value, self.node[self.LEFT], None)

    def insert_value_right(self, value):
        """Inserts value to the right of this node.
        Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
        """      
        self.node[self.RIGHT] = ListBinaryTree(value, None, self.node[self.RIGHT])

    def insert_tree_left(self, tree):
        """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
        self.node[self.LEFT] = tree

    def insert_tree_right(self, tree):
        """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
        self.node[self.RIGHT] = tree

    def set_value(self, new_value):
        """Sets the value of the node."""
        self.node[self.DATA] = new_value

    def get_value(self):
        """Gets the value of the node."""
        return self.node[self.DATA]

    def get_left_subtree(self):
        """Gets the left subtree of the node."""
        return self.node[self.LEFT]

    def get_right_subtree(self):
        """Gets the right subtree of the node."""
        return self.node[self.RIGHT]

    def __str__(self):
        return '['+str(self.node[self.DATA])+', '+str(self.node[self.LEFT])+', '+\
 str(self.node[self.RIGHT])+']'
```

Objective:
[image]

Comment: Is the API of that `buildtree` function something that's been specified for you in your assignment, or is that just your current best attempt? Because, I'd suggest moving most of the code you have in your `main` function to the `buildtree` function and making the function signature `buildtree(inorder, preorder)`. I'll admit though that your Tree class doesn't make much sense to me (why are you using lists rather than attributes?) so I don't know exactly how to integrate it into the recursive code.

Comment: Everything in the first box of code is just my best attempt, I dont actually know what im doing, so ignore it if it doesnt make sense. Like in the OP im just at a loss I need spoon feed.

Comment: The Class was given to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've just about got it, you've just put too much of your logic in the setup code and not realized that the recursive code is going to be the same thing.

It will be a lot easier if you change the API of your recursive `buildtree` function to simply take the whole `inorder` and `preorder` sequences and return a tree built out of them.

```
def buildtree(inorder, preorder):
    root_val = preorder[0]
    left_size = inorder.index(root_val) # size of the left subtree

    if left_size > 0:
        left = buildtree(inorder[:left_size], preorder[1:left_size+1])
    else:
        left = None

    if (left_size + 1) < len(inorder):
        right = buildtree(inorder[left_size+1:], preorder[left_size+1:])
    else:
        right = None

    return ListBinaryTree(root_val, left, right)
```

Comment: thank you so much, you cant imagine how much frustration I went though, I will learn a lot from this.